# Conditional Formatting Based on Adjacent Range Cell Value

Tags: excel, formatting, range, conditional-statements, cell

HI I couldn't figure this out how to do this Conditional Formatting . I can understand i have to use `AND` formula, Tried a lot with `AND` formula but couldn't figure this out.

I want to color Delivery Dates based on Days. Delivery Date is in `K Column` and Days in `M Column`.  First i select Delivery Dates (To be Formatted) then Tried this Formula `=and($M7:$M16<=9,$M7:$M16>=1)`. But it didn't worked.

i want to Color all Delivery Dates which in Between 9 and 1 Days.

Please Help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm8cZ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify only one cell in your formula.
Try `=AND($M7<=9,$M7>=1)`

The principle of **Conditional Formatting** is as below. The formula will apply to the top-left cell of the range you given. And it offsets to other cells in your range. Therefore, for column `K7`, knowing the value of `M7` is enough to determine that `K7` should be colored or not.

BTW, I suggest you that don't just tell us *not working*, but state more clearly about *what's the result*. It may be an error, an unexpected result, or nothing happened, or something else.

Comment: Thanks . Is there any formula which will work on whole selected Range like $M1:$M100 instead of individual cell .

Comment: You don't need to set up the formula individually. In the conditional formatting management window, there is a column which can let you decide the range you want to format. However I can't tell you the precise name of the window and the column since I'm using non-eng version.